# Showing Notifications While Activating Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks

I want to give errors like this, while activating my plugin.

[image]

Which hooks should i use ? Can you share simple examples ?

In shortly,when user activate my plugin, is a directory's CHMOD isn't 777 , i'll warn it and stop activation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out : [WP Error](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error)

And this link covers how the plugin activation error works: http://www.squarepenguin.com/wordpress/?p=6

And I don't see any reason why you should ever chmod a directory to 777

Comment: I think he wants to recreate the warning messages that appear on top of the admin screen.  All WP_Error does is give you a way of storing errors in an object.

Comment: @MannyFleurmond right. I want to generate custom errors and CHMOD 777 just an example :)